# Unable to open android studio in my ionic project

Tags: android, ionic-framework

```
Unable to launch Android Studio. Is it installed?
[capacitor]   Attempted to open Android Studio at: /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
[capacitor]   You can configure this with the CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH environment variable.
```

Comment: Have you configured at enviroment variables ?

Comment: Which operating system are you using ?